# Set track number from file name in MP3 music management software

Tags: mp3, music, gui

I have .mp3 files, whose names and titles are their track numbers.

- For example:  "Track01.mp3" (the internal title property reads "Track01")

How do I let my MP3 management software know that it's track 1 of a CD?  (I'm using Sony's SonicStage to manage my music.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the track number tags.

If you didn't mind software specifically to fix tags, you could probably use [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) to mass fix the track number tag in the file. Its a little tricky with no obvious deliminator between tracks, unless they are *all* called Track (tracknumber) however. You'd probably want to use the filename -> tag option, use "track%track%" to use the filename to populate track numbers

The autonumbering wizard option might prove helpful as well.

Comment: They are all called "Track[#]"

Comment: edited to reflect that it works, and what arguments to use

Comment: (+1) After some long manual effort, the Autonumbering wizard really helped.  Thanks.