# set CD number from folder name

Tags: mp3, music, tags, music-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to organize music?](https://superuser.com/questions/87792/how-to-organize-music)
>   [Set track number from file name in MP3 music management software](https://superuser.com/questions/358285/set-track-number-from-file-name-in-mp3-music-management-software)

I have 278 MP3 files, arranged by the CD they came from.  I have 27 folders each named "CD [#]"

How can I use the folder's name as a tag for each of my MP3 files?

Comment: Yeah, everything he's asking is doable off the same software. There's just this tiny learning curve, then WHAM, its almost like magic.

Comment: oops to slow again. This donateware audio file tag editor with extensive automation capability might do it?  http://forums.mp3tag.de/index.php?showtopic=10501&hl=tag+folder .  I would be testing it on a backup set first seeing all the possible things (or bugs) that could happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/), it will need a little tweaking but something like `c:\pathtofiles\%discnumber%\%dummy%` should work in the filenames to tag option would work.

Really its the ONLY tagger you need, once you get a hang of it.